# Matlab - Find points in vicinity

Tags: matlab, dataset, multivariate-testing

Lets say I have a dataset like below.

X = [170,85;
165,75;
180,100;
190,120;
160,80;
170,70];

a distance vector

Y = [10,20];

a data point

Z = [166,77];

I want to find all the points of X that fall within the distance Y from the point Z

Answer should be 
ans = [170,85;
165,75;
160,80;
170,70]

How can I do this in Matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a= X(abs(X(:,1)-Z(1))<=Y(1) & abs(X(:,2)-Z(2))<=Y(2),:)
```

**EDIT**

Multidimensional solution can look like this:

```
a= X(all(abs(X-ones(size(X,1),1)*Z) <= ones(size(X,1),1)*Y,2),:)
```

Comment: Ok. So, this works fine for the above example but I provided example just to clearify what I want to do. For my actual task I have a dataset with lot more dimensions. So, above method will require too much effort. I was looking for something like `rangesearch`
Thanks anyway :)